# В чем разница типа возвращаемого по значению и по ссылке?

Tags: c++, ссылки

В чем разница у этих двух функций?

**Первая:**

```
int &Time:։badSetHour( int hh )
{
    hour = ( hh >= 0 && hh < 24 ) ? hh : 0;
    return hour; 
}
```

**Вторая:**

```
int Time:։ibadSetHour( int hh )
{
    hour = ( hh >= 0 && hh < 24 ) ? hh : 0;
    return &hour; 
}
```

Comment: Код невалидный. Нет определения `hour`.

Comment: @alexolut, а вторая функция правильно составлена?

Comment: они в этой части не отличаются.

Comment: Вы перепутали `&` как модификатор типа и унарный оператор взятия адреса `&`. К сожалению, в C++ для этих кардинально разных вещей используется один и тот же знак, что приводит к путанице. Претензии направляйте лично Страуструпу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct Time
{
  int hour;
  int setHour(int h) { hour = (0 <= h && h < 24) ? h : 0; return hour; }
  int& setHourRef(int h) { hour = (0 <= h && h < 24) ? h : 0; return hour; } 
}
```

Видимо, имеется в виду что-то вроде этого. Разница в том, что первая функция возвращает копию члена `hour`, вторая - ссылку на него (`lvalue`) и можно использовать как `Time t; t.setHourRef(1) = 2;` (код вполне бессмысленный, но валидный)

---

Как уже отмечено в комментариях, важно различать модификатор типа `&`:

```
int& foo(...); // функция возвращает ссылку на целое
void bar(int& value); // функция с аргументом типа ссылка на целое
```

и оператор взятия адреса `&`:

```
int a = 0; double b = 42.0;
int* pointerInt = &a; // сохраняем адрес переменной а в указатель
double* pointerDouble = &b; // адрес переменной b -в указатель double*
```

Comment: а в первой функции если написать return &hour?

Comment: Смотри комментарий VladD. Дополню ответ.

Comment: @Estet `return &hour;` вернет указатель на целое, что противоречит объявленному типу функции.